# Navigate in source control explorer by local path instead of TFS path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

In the Visual Studio 2013 Source Control Explorer, you can type a TFS path in the source location and hit enter, and it will display the files located in that TFS location.

But the local path (if any) is not editable. Is there a way (built in, or plugin), that I can enter a local file path (i.e. c:\tfs\myapp\folder1\folder2\folder3), and it will take me there (if mapped)?

I often have long TFS paths, and I don't remember where things are by heart. So, I will navigate to the location in Windows Explorer. But, I can't paste that into source control explorer, so I have to navigate there a second time. Would be great if I could just paste that into Source Control Explorer.

Comment: This is a great suggestion; I'll make sure it goes on our backlog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution but do simplify your work.

1. Open `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2013` in order to use TF.exe;
2. Navigate source code local folder;
3. type `tf info *` or `tf dir` or `tf property *`;

Some server path will be displayed for your use.

Another option is to install Team Foundation Server Power Tool so that you can perform most operations in Windows Explorer instead of Source Control Explorer. You can install it from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f or *Extensions And Tools* within Visual Studio.

Comment: via TFPT, in file explorer, it's right click -> tfs -> "workspace"

Comment: I wonder if this could be written as a shell extension. Right click -> tf info for current working directory